# Order a matrix depending on row and column of another in R

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr

Hello I need to order column and row names in a mtrix according to another matrix, here is an exemple

```
M1
  D E F
A 1 2 3
B 4 5 6
C 7 8 9

M2 
  F D E
C T F F 
A F T T
```

So here I would like to 1 sort the `M2` columns in order to  have the same as `M1`
and then sort the rows (as you can see here there is not the `row B` as in `M1`, so I simply add a new one filled by `F` letters.

```
New_M2
  D E F
A T T F
B F F F
C F F T
```

I know for exemple how to sort the column using `M2[,colnames(M1)]` but that is all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1.** Match column and row names of `M1` and `M2`

```
M3 <- M2[match(rownames(M1), rownames(M2)),
         match(colnames(M1), colnames(M2))]

#          D     E     F
# A     TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# <NA>    NA    NA    NA
# C    FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

**Step 2.** Set the dimnames and replace missing values with `FALSE`

```
dimnames(M3) <- dimnames(M1)
M3[is.na(M3)] <- FALSE

#       D     E     F
# A  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# B FALSE FALSE FALSE
# C FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

***Data***

```
M1 <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, T, dimnames = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E", "F")))
M2 <- matrix(c(T, F, F, T, F, T), 2, 3, dimnames = list(c("C", "A"), c("F", "D", "E")))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help it works like a charme

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way but perhaps it isn't the best one :

```
#Get the rownames which are missing
diff_row <- setdiff(rownames(m1), rownames(m2))
#Create a matrix with `FALSE` values for those rownames
m3 <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = length(diff_row), ncol = ncol(m2), 
              dimnames = list(diff_row, colnames(m2)))
#rbind it to m2 matrix
m4 <- rbind(m2, m3)
#rearrange based on m1 matrix
m4[rownames(m1), colnames(m1)]

#      D     E     F
#A  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
#B FALSE FALSE FALSE
#C FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```